# Clion console showing previous compile

Tags: compilation, console, clion

Hello i have little problem, i just started with C and download CLion. Everything is ok before i changed file. On the previous version of file was something like

```
int c;
c=getchar()
putchar(c);
```

Now i changed file to

```
int c, nl, nw, nc, state;
    state = OUT;
    nl = nw = nc = 0;
    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        ++nc;
        if (c == '\n') {
            ++nl;
        }
        if (c == ' ' || c == '\n' || c == '\t') {
            state = OUT;
        } else if (state == OUT) {
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", nl, nw, nc);
```

But after build and run console is like using first version(getchar and putchar). When i run program from directory normal is looks good. I think i need change some configuration but cant find any solution. using "clean" on Run didnt help. Is funny because after create new project is still previous program output :DD

Answer (score 0):

You can try Tools->Cmake->Reload Cmake Project

Comment: please try also Reset Cache and Reload Cmake Project

Comment: was trying and no reasults